# ITfoxtec SAML 4.8.8: Completely ignore validation of AuthnContext

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

we are using the latest version of ITFoxtec (4.8.8) to parse saml2responses received from our IDP.

The AuthnContext looks like this:

```
<saml:AuthnContext>
<saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>
</saml:AuthnContext>
```

unfortunately while calling ReadSamlResponse

```
var genericSamlRequest = Request.ToGenericHttpRequest();
var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
var authResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(configuration);
binding.ReadSamlResponse(genericSamlRequest, authResponse);
```

we are getting the following null exception

```
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext.set_ClassReference(Uri value)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
```

is there any workaround or way to ignore entirely the AuthnContext with SAML validation?

this code fails and we have no idea on how to bypass:

```
var binding = new Saml2PostBinding(); 
var authResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(configuration);
binding.ReadSamlResponse(genericSamlRequest, authResponse);
```

we cannot modify the response because it is encrypted and signed. The signature validation will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AuthnContextDeclRef` is not supported but it should be removed in [this line](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Tokens/Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler.cs#L139).

The `AuthnContextClassRef` is supported:

```
<saml:AuthnContext>
     <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</saml:AuthnContext>
```

Comment: Indeed it seems it is removed, but as a result, the context is empty and the validation is looking for 

<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>

 

Thus, the code should then replace AuthnContextDeclRef by AuthnContextClassRef when no AuthnContextClassRef is present.

Comment: The issue is resolved in version 4.10.1:  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.10.1